# Network error while using API on localhost, with Jest & React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using the React testing library and Jest, and trying to mock a GET request to my backend which runs also on my localhost (on different port).

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import FetchMock from "jest-fetch-mock";
import MyComponent from "../MyComponent";

describe("MyComponent", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    FetchMock.resetMocks();
  });

  it("renders correct data", async () => {
    const mockData = { data: "foo" };
    FetchMock.once(JSON.stringify(mockData))

    const { findAllByText } = render(
      <MyComponent url={'localhost:4000'} />
    );

    const text= await findAllByText(/foo/);
    expect(text).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

In my tests configuration, I've added this line too:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:4000';
```

It seems like there is a problem with using the localhost, as I am getting this error:

```
console.error node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:52
    Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
        at Object.dispatchError (path\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:65:19)
        at Request.<anonymous> (path\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:676:20)
        at Request.emit (events.js:201:15)
        at Request.onRequestError (path\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:196:13)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:402:9)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:196:13)
        at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
        at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:17) undefined
```

This is my component (`MyComponent.js`):

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function MyComponent(url) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState('');
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      axios.get(`${url}/foo`)
        .then(res => {
          setData(res.data)
        })
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <h1>{data}</h1>
  );
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your full code as well?

Comment: You mean the component code? In the component I am dispatching a GET request to the given API (localhost:4000/endpoint)

Comment: I'm gonna check if you're using `axios` in your implementation. If you use it, why don't you `jest-mock-axios` instead?

Comment: Good point, thanks! I tried it also with `jest-mock-axios` but am still getting the exact same error. I added the component code in the description by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding to your case, it looks pretty easy to deal with. You don't have to need any other package to mock your endpoint. You can mock `axios` directly via `jest`.

Here is the idea (take a look at the inline comments where you need to add):

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import axios from "axios";
import MyComponent from "../MyComponent";

// Mock axios directly
jest.mock('axios')

describe("MyComponent", () => {

  it("renders correct data", async () => {
    const mockData = { data: "foo" };
    
    // Mock returning your value
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue(mockData);

    const { findAllByText } = render(
      <MyComponent url={'localhost:4000'} />
    );

    const text= await findAllByText(/foo/);
    expect(text).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```